# iOS linkedin share not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, shared-libraries, linkedin-api

I could not make work the new linkedin sdk. It just open the login view. When i logged in then it go to linked in account/profile rather then showing the share prompt. Do anyone have any blog or example with latest sdk ?
It just wasted my 3 days. Please help.

```
NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:LISDK_W_SHARE_PERMISSION, nil];

[LISDKSessionManager createSessionWithAuth:permissions state:nil showGoToAppStoreDialog:YES successBlock:^(NSString *returnState)
 {
     NSLog(@"%s","success called!");

     NSString *url = @"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares";
     NSString *payload = @"{\"comment\":\"Check out developer.linkedin.com! http://linkd.in/1FC2PyG\",\"visibility\":{ \"code\":\"anyone\" }}";

     if ([LISDKSessionManager hasValidSession])

     {

         [[LISDKAPIHelper sharedInstance] postRequest:url stringBody:payload
                                              success:^(LISDKAPIResponse *response)
          {

              // do something with response

              NSLog(@"response : %@",response.data);
          }
                                                error:^(LISDKAPIError *apiError) {
                                                    // do something with error
                                                    NSLog(@"error: %@",apiError);
                                                }];
     }


 }
                                errorBlock:^(NSError *error){
                                    NSLog(@"%s","error called!");
                                }];
```

//

Comment: Hello. You could start with showing some of your code, maybe there is some kind of mistake, there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue.This is an effective method but not a good idea: `UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://developer.linkedin.com&title=LinkedIn%20Developer%20Network&summary=My%20favorite%20developer%20program&source=LinkedIn")!)`
If you successfully share something via the SDK for iOS,please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a URL like this and hyperlink your share button/icon/text...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Source: **[Microsoft LinkedIn Share URL Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

For example, this works for me:

> https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http://www.wikipedia.org/

Works fine:

[image]